# Link to article with anchor

Tags: menu-item, joomla3.8

I have following site structure, 2 big anchored articles:

- Frontpage, url=/, menu item type=article
- About Us, url=index.html#about-us
- Contacts, url=index.html#contacts
- Article1, url=articles.html#article1
- Article2, url=articles.html#article2

Those are all separate menu items.

index.html is necessary so it works on articles page. But can I get rid of this? Its bad also in that sense that when frontpage has link e.g "#contacts" it will reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, then you can have the full domain followed by the anchor. E.g. `https://www.your website.com/#contacts` and  `https://www.your website.com/#about-us`. This would ensure that the page doesn't have to be reloaded if someone clicks on any of the above links.

Comment: You'll need to choose the menu item type external URL